# Edge detection in openCv gives runtime error

Tags: image-processing, opencv, edge-detection

I have used cvCanny function to detect Edges.

```
cvCanny( img_b, out, lowThresh*N*N, highThresh*N*N, aperature_size );
```

But in run time it gives runtime error. The error msg not clear at all. It refers some memory location. Please help me..!!

code:

```
void switch_callback_h( int position ){
 highInt = position;
}
void switch_callback_l( int position ){
 lowInt = position;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

 const char* name = "Edge Detection Window";
 // Kernel size
 int N = 7;
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
IplImage* frame;

while(1) {
frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

// Add convolution boarders
 CvPoint offset = cvPoint((N-1)/2,(N-1)/2);
 cvCopyMakeBorder(frame, img_b, offset, IPL_BORDER_REPLICATE, cvScalarAll(0));

 // Make window
 cvNamedWindow( name, 1 );

 // Edge Detection Variables
 int aperature_size = N;
 double lowThresh = 20;
 double highThresh = 40;

 // Create trackbars
 cvCreateTrackbar( "High", name, &high_switch_value, 4, switch_callback_h );
 cvCreateTrackbar( "Low", name, &low_switch_value, 4, switch_callback_l );
 highThresh = 800;
        lowThresh = 100;

     cvCanny( img_b, out, lowThresh*N*N, highThresh*N*N, aperature_size );  

        cvShowImage(name, out);
 cvReleaseImage( &frame );
 cvReleaseImage( &img_b );
 cvReleaseImage( &out );
 cvDestroyWindow( name );

   if( cvWaitKey( 15 ) == 27 ) 
 break;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual error message - also what compiler, OS, etc ?

Comment: Your thresholds look like they are far too high. What is the format of img_b and out? Run gdb so you can give backtrace when the exception is thrown!

Comment: Do try and give a link to the entire source code. As this seems more like a debugging question than logical errors. I'm trying to run your code.

Comment: Try and remove as much irrelevant code as possible.  Trackbars, the convolution borders, etc -- you don't need them to reproduce the problem.  If it turns out that you do, then you know what the problem is :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were **very close** to making this work.  Basically, here are your problems:

- You're creating a window inside the loop.  Since the window has the same name every time, you only to create it once.
- You're destroying your images before you're able to show them.  Your images will be shown not when you called `cvShowImage`, but when you call `cvWaitKey`.  By that time you've already freed the image, so nothing will be shown.
- You're freeing frames loaded from `CvCapture`.  The documentation explicitly says **not** to do this:

> The function cvQueryFrame grabs a
>   frame from a camera or video file,
>   decompresses it and returns it. This
>   function is just a combination of
>   GrabFrame and RetrieveFrame , but in
>   one call. **The returned image should
>   not be released or modified by the
>   user**. In the event of an error, the
>   return value may be NULL.

- You're not initializing `image_b` or `out` anywhere.  They're not even declared in the code you posted.  **I don't know how your code even compiled, let alone ran**.
- You're specifying `image_b` as the source to the canny edge detection, when it should really be `frame`
- You're not freeing the video capture struct

Like I said, a number of tiny points.  Here's code that works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
//
// Comment this out to use the webcam.
//
#define LOAD_IMAGE "/home/misha/Desktop/Lenna.png"
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *name = "Edge Detection Window";
    int N = 7;
#ifndef LOAD_IMAGE
    CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
#endif
    IplImage *frame = NULL;
    IplImage *out = NULL;

    cvNamedWindow(name, 1);

    while (1) 
    {
#ifdef LOAD_IMAGE
        frame = cvLoadImage(LOAD_IMAGE, 0);
#else
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
#endif
        out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(frame), frame->depth, frame->nChannels);

        int aperature_size = N;
        double lowThresh = 20;
        double highThresh = 40;

        highThresh = 800;
        lowThresh = 100;

        cvCanny(frame, out, lowThresh * N * N, highThresh * N * N,
                aperature_size);

        cvShowImage(name, out);
#ifndef LOAD_IMAGE
        if (cvWaitKey(15) == 27)
            break;
#else
        cvWaitKey(0);
        break;
#endif
        }
    cvReleaseImage(&out);
    cvDestroyWindow(name);
#ifdef LOAD_IMAGE
    cvReleaseImage(&frame);
#else
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Compiles with:

```
gcc -ggdb -Wall -o devan.out devan.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Standard image and output:

[image: lenna] [image: output]

Comment: I want to do this in real time.

Comment: @devon: Just comment out the "break;" line at the end of the loop, and it will continue to process. (And comment out the LOAD_IMAGE.)

Nice code/nice answer, @misha!